# animation in game application in android

Tags: android-animation

I am working on image animation. I have 200 transparent png images which I am trying to show one by one over a background image.

Can you tell me the best way to do it. The image should change in such a way that it should appear that a cartoon is running.

thanx

pavan

Answer (score 0):

Did you end up finding a solution for this? I would be interested in knowing. If you do not need to animate quicker than every 300ms then this may work for you see my post:

See: [750 frame transparent PNG animation in ImageView at 23fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528116/750-frame-transparent-png-animation-in-imageview-at-23fps)

Also using Animation.drawable could be an option if you can split your cartoon it up into small pieces 40-50 frames at a time and then play them one after the other.

I'm still looking for a better solution for this so would be interested to see another way.